# R Recode Variable In List

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data=data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                Y = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,1))
```

I have data with column X and wish to recode with this rule:
if X equals to 1,5,6,9 then Y equals to 1 but if X equals to 2,3,4 then Y equals to 0 and if X equals to 7,8 then Y equals to 2. I am wondering, how to do this with not using 'if' statements. Maybe on dplyr, data.table for example.

Comment: Take a look at the `case_when` function from `dplyr`

Comment: @MrFlick I take a look at the case_when function from dplyr but see that the values are listed separately.

Comment: You don't want to list the values separately like this? `data %>% mutate(Y = case_when(X %in% c(1, 5, 6, 9) ~ 1,  X %in% c(2:4) ~ 0,  X %in% c(7, 8) ~ 2))` ? There is similar `fcase` in `data.table`.

Comment: @Ronak Shah what if there are values not listed in the code? Like if you wish to say 'if the value in the column is not one of the one's listed then set it to 999' ?

Comment: You can use condition `TRUE`  for all the remaining values: `data %>% 
  mutate(Y = case_when(X %in% c(1, 5, 6, 9) ~ 1, X %in% c(2:4) ~ 0,  X %in% c(7, 8) ~ 2, TRUE ~ 999))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below without `if`

```
v1 <- c(1,5,6,9)
v2 <- c(2,3,4)
v3 <- c(7,8)

dfout <- within(data,Y <- 1*(X %in% v1) + 0*(X %in% v2) + 2*(X %in% v3))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  X Y
1 1 1
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 4 0
5 5 1
6 6 1
7 7 2
8 8 2
9 9 1
```

Comment: thanks so much it work like a charm. Do you know of data.table solution since the data is large?

Comment: @bvowe This will also work with `data.table` : `setDT(data)[, Y := 1*(X %in% v1) + 0*(X %in% v2) + 2*(X %in% v3)]`

Comment: @Ronak Shah this is good and my last question how can i Add one more category say value 5 for values not listed?